# using foreach like an expression

Tags: kotlin

I would like to use a foreach loop as an expression (just for fun) but i'm not able to do it, and i'm stuck on it

In my example i want to convert a String to a bytecode representation of this String.

What's working, but is ugly in my opinion

```
fun bytecoderepr(arg: String):String {
    var bcr:String = ""
    arg.toByteArray().forEach {
        bcr += it.toString()
    }
    return bcr
}
```

Works as expected and returns "10399111110102524848" for "gconf400"

What's not working, but i'd like to achieve

```
fun bytecoderepr(arg: String):String =
    arg.toByteArray().forEach().toString()
```

Won't compile because foreach requires an "action".

I can convert my array to string, but it dont return the bytcode representation but a conversion in string of bytecodes

```
fun bytecoderepr(arg: String):String =
    arg.toByteArray().toString()
```

Returns "[B@1a407d53"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) function:

```
fun bytecoderepr(arg: String) = arg.toByteArray().joinToString("")
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect !

Answer (score 2):

Another option is, you could do `java.util.Arrays.toString(arg.toByteArray())`.

It's less method invocations and compact than `joinToString("")` but less flexible (for ex: cannot specify the separator).

Comment: Yeah, but it prints `[103, 99, 111, 110, 102, 52, 48, 48]`

Comment: Yes, mentioned in the answer.